# How to merge bottom border to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to merge the footer border to the bottom of the page. I have no actual border just the background colour.
The results I want to achieve:

[image]

I have tried using padding bottom, border-bottom-style but it is still not merging.

My code:

```css
footer {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <p id="footername">Example Text</p>
        <p>Example Text</p>
        <p>Example Text</p>
    </footer>
```

[image]

I basically want the bottom white line to go away so that the grey background will connect to bottom page as seen in the first picture

Comment: Seems like you are not resetting the default body margin. Add `margin: 0` to body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy to go, just use `position: absolute;` and set `bottom: 0;`

```css
footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <p id="footername">Example Text</p>
        <p>Example Text</p>
        <p>Example Text</p>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I recommend you to open Console tab in Dev Tools and check if it is a margin or padding and what causes this. If it is a body margin then you can simply do `margin: 0` on body element or try doing `*{margin:0;  padding: 0;  box-sizing: border-box}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you make your footer stick to the bottom of the page. You will have to add `position:fixed`. Then adjust the `bottom:0` to make sure it is at the bottom

```css
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <p id="footername">Example Text</p>
        <p>Example Text</p>
        <p>Example Text</p>
    </footer>
```